# Streaming data into VideoPlayerController with a Proxy

Tags: flutter, dart, networking, video, proxy

I am trying to create a proxy server in my app in order to cache videos. For opening a video I use the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package with the

`VideoPlayerController.network("127.0.0.1:8080/http://127.0.0.1:8080/99e61720-935c-494e-aaab-0c2529716311.mp4");` which is received by our proxy server in the app and redirects the request to the main server.

i.e. VideoPlayerController sends request to view a video

1. Proxy server redirects request from VideoPlayerController to main server
2. Proxy server receives response
3. Proxy server streams response to VideoPlayerController

[image: It should look like this]

The problem right now is that streaming the video from the proxy to the VideoPlayer is not working. We have tried to save the video file from the proxy response and it was working, but streaming it to the VideoPlayer wasn't.
This is the full code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class ProxyServer {

HttpServer server;
var client = 0;

static File file;
static bool hasFile = false;

Future<void> init() async {

    try{
      server = await HttpServer.bind("127.0.0.1", 8080, shared: true);
      print("Server running on IP : " + server.address.toString() + " On Port : " + server.port.toString());

    }catch(e){
      print("Something went wrong while creating a server...");
      return;
    }

    print("Listening...");
    listen();
}

 Future<void> listen() async {

     await for (HttpRequest request in server) {

         List<int> _bytes = [];
         var _received = 0;
         var _total = 0;

         http.Request baseRequest = new http.Request('GET', Uri.parse("http://d9txtuxofddt9.cloudfront.net${request.uri}"));
         Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();

         request.headers.forEach((key, value) {
             print(key + ", " + value.first);
             if(key != "host")
                 headers[key] = value.toString();
             else
                 headers["host"] = "d9txtuxofddt9.cloudfront.net";
         });

         baseRequest.headers.addAll(headers);
         print("Base Request: " + baseRequest.headers.toString());

         http.StreamedResponse proxyResponse = await http.Client().send(baseRequest);
         _total = proxyResponse.contentLength;

         String destFilePath = "${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}${request.uri}";
         file = File(destFilePath);

         proxyResponse.headers.forEach((key, value) {
             request.response.headers.add(key, value);
         });

         proxyResponse.stream.listen((value) {
             _bytes.addAll(value);
             _received += value.length;
             print("${_received ~/ 1024} / ${_total ~/ 1024} KB");

             request.response.add(value);
             file.writeAsBytesSync(_bytes);

         }).onDone(() async {
             print("File saved at : ${file.path}");
             request.response.close();
         });
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I stream the response from the server back to flutter's VideoPlayerController?